# Mongoose memory limit when using sort

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose aggregate to join two tables and I want to sort the results, but when I run the query, I get this error:

`MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Sort exceeded memory limit of 33554432 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.`

and I am using `allowDiskUse(true)` but it's not working. This is my code:

```js
Model.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { from: 'collection', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'ref', as: 'other' } },
  { $set: { other: { $arrayElemAt: ['$other', 0] } } },
  { $sort: { 'something': 1 } },
  { $skip: 50000 },
  { $limit: 100 },
]).allowDiskUse(true).then((results) => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Seems like code is fine, and limit is from MongoDB atlas free cluster. Is this correct?

Comment: Move the `$sort` to the first stage since it won't impact the results and add an index on `{ something: 1 }`. Otherwise we need version info to assist

Comment: How many documents are there and what is the datatype for the value of something?

Comment: @Charchit Kapoor About +51K documents and I tried with string and date.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is coming from MongoDB Atlas Free Cluster. It doesn't support `allowDiskUse` option. See the limits [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations).

As a workaround, what you can try is creating an index on the key `something`. Like this:

```
db.collectionName.createIndex({something: 1})
```

Also, modify your pipeline as follows:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { $sort: { 'something': 1 } },
  { $skip: 50000 },
  { $limit: 100 },
  { $lookup: { from: 'collection', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'ref', as: 'other' } },
  { $set: { other: { $arrayElemAt: ['$other', 0] } } },
]).allowDiskUse(true).then((results) => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

The `sort` stage is moved to the top, so that index can be utilized. Also, `skip` and `limit` are applied before `$lookup` to optimize the `lookup`.

Comment: Why would the error appear again with larger data size?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that for another answer and mistakingly typed it here. The error shouldn't come now. @user20042973.